# NH 3.3.1 + Castle.Windsor 3.0 + WCF is there a way to work them together?

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate, castle-windsor, integration

### In my current project I use NH 3.0 + CW 2.5.2 + NHIntegrationFacility 1.1 + WCF, and now i need to migrate to the latest NH 3.3.1. But I see that NHIntegrationFacility doesn't supported since 2.0RC(that support NH3.1) version.

UPDATE: Thanks for reply guys. Is threre some alternative DI framework that can work with NH, WCF, have simple AOP and DI abilities and have active development?

Comment: i never got around checking out the NH integration facility. What exactly does/did it provide?

Comment: Integration facility project is probably dead together with active record. Even if you will manage to build it against latest Nhibernate, you will need to it each new release. We are planing to remove this facility from project, but its not as simple as we would like :(

Comment: why would you want to move away from NHibernate? You don't need the NH Facility, i use WCF+Windsor+NHibernate without any problems, it works just fine.

Comment: Dirk, no, i wouldn't. I want to use NHibernate and Windsor(for injecting and AOP wcf services) in my project, but i don't know how to do that without NHibernateIntegration facaility. Please can u explain me how to do that? or give me some links.

Comment: as i posted in my first comment, i don't even know what the NH facility provided. In my own projects, i have a class (singleton lifestyle) that holds the NH session factory and is responsible for creating it when it is first needed. That class can then be injected wherever i need an isession. In my own project i implemented a unit of work pattern, so there is an additional layer between the repositories and the session factory, holding on to the ISession and an ITransaction representing the current unit of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirk, it is impossible! but when u post your comment, i try to remove the dependency to this asssembly and configure NHibernate by classic method (NHibernate.Cdg.Configuration) and regiser ISession with wcf facility simple: Component.For().LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation().UsingFactoryMethod(session‌​Factory.OpenSession). And project working perfect without that perfectly. Thank u dude! :)